# How did fictional asteroid 2019 PDC get its name?

Tags: nasa, asteroid, identify-this-object, impact, near-earth-asteroid

Gizmodo's [NASA and FEMA Will Simulate an Impending Asteroid Strike Next Week](https://gizmodo.com/nasa-and-fema-will-simulate-an-impending-asteroid-strik-1834308695)

The hypothetical discovery takes place in 2019, but what does "PDC" stand for?

Perhaps it is another "discovery" by the famous Professor Peter Schickele?

---

[image: fictional asteroid 2019 PDC]

[image: fictional asteroid 2019 PDC]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scenario is presented by the [2019 **P**lanetary **D**efense **C**onference](https://cneos.jpl.nasa.gov/pd/cs/pdc19/).

Comment: rats, I was hoping for "pretty d**n catastrophic".

Comment: @uhoh I wouldn't be surprised if something like that was being used internally ;-)